# Parse Enum by value using SnakeYAML

Tags: enums, yaml, snakeyaml

As specified in the [docs](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Enum) and seen from the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java?r=0b1595fa3ef864abb3bd0e5c69f279da83f6fcab), SnakeYAML works with enums by their names. What I'd like to have is to parse values by enum value, e.g.:

Enum:

```
public enum Strategy {
    ALWAYS_RUN("always-run"),
    ALWAYS_SKIP("always-skip"),
    DEPENDS("depends");
    ...
}
```

YAML:

```
branches:
  trunk: always-skip
  bugfix: depends
  default: always-run
```

The reason is our code style forces us to use uppercase for enum constants, while I'd like to keep data in the yaml file lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible. Enum constants are private, and are therefore not accessible by other classes, so the YAML parser would not be able to construct the objects.

Although not perfect, you could use [aliases](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Aliases) to create a nickname for the enums.

Comment: Hm, interesting concept.
Well, for enums there's `valueOf` method that could be utilized, if only SnakeYAML had this handling internally.

Comment: I was taking a look for you to see if you could include a yaml file in another yaml file, so define all the aliases in a yaml and then just include it in all the others, so as to hide the aliases. Unfortunately this is not possible :( I think you're just going to have to cope with uppercase in your yaml.

Comment: or just parse them as strings and maybe do conversion to enums in the code

Comment: I was going to suggest that one too. Just store them as strings and then convert them to enums in the java object :)

Comment: I was also wondering if you could get snakeyaml to use a method other than `valueOf(...)`, but then I found this article: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snakeyaml-core/iNMU_9nH90s

Sounds like its pretty much impossible. But Yeah, if you want to keep it lower case I would store them as strings then parse them when they are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this. Probably it's not clean but works properly.

1. Create a new Constructor class by extending `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor`.
2. Inside it create a `ScalarConstuctor` `protected class` with the same code implementation as in base `ScalarConstructor` class except of enum parsing implementation.
3. In a method `constructStandardJavaInstance` check if an `enum` exists  with uppercase or lowercase name.
4. Finally create `Yaml` object with the Constructor (of step 1)

Comment: For posterity... I created fork from upstream snakeyaml repository and I added  the ability to configure case sensitivity - https://github.com/asomov/snakeyaml/pull/14. I am waiting for approval of the pull request and adding it to the master branch

Comment: My pull-request have been accepted. It will be delivered in version 1.28

Comment: Sadly the link to the PR is broken now. Do you know if the PR was migrated?

Comment: Repository was migrated, probably without any PR history but changes was already delivered so you can use this feature in current version of snakeyaml

Comment: @RickMoritz Here you have these changes (line 515) -  https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/src/master/src/main/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/Constructor.java